# Nested SELECT using results from first SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to list all customers who were referred to a bookstore by another customer, listing each customer's last name and the customer# who made the referral.

Easy enough, but I'm trying to add onto the query by also listing the referring customer's first and last name from the same table and data.

Referred column is the customer# of the person who referred them.

```
SELECT lastname, a.referred || ' ' || a.firstname || ' ' || a.lastname "Referred By:"
  FROM customers 
    WHERE referred =
    (SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname FROM customers WHERE customer# = a.referred);
```

My expected result is something like

```
Lastname: Referred By:

Gina      1003 Leila Smith
```

Getting this error:

```
ORA-00904: "A"."LASTNAME": invalid identifier

00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Am I correct in thinking I might need to do the nested select in the SELECT clause itself?
Thank you.

Comment: You can only use aliases like that in SELECT clause if they are defined in the same queries FROM clause. i.e. - SELECT alias_here.col FROM tab alias_here

Comment: You can either `left outer join` the customers table for the referral information back to the customers table, or you could use a scalar subquery to retrieve the details in the select list. Which is more performant for your data is up to you to test.

Comment: Won't be possible to do it this way. Please share some sample data and expected results so we can re-write your SQL from scratch.

Comment: You haven't defined the alias `a` anywhere. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self-join the table.

Assuming that the  `customers` table has a column called `referred` that contains the `customer#` of the referring customer:

```
SELECT 
    c.lastname, 
    c.referred || ' ' || r.firstname || ' ' || r.lastname "Referred By:"
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN customers r ON r.customer# = c.referred
```

Comment: I actually wasn't aware that you could self-join a table, thank you! This way works too (:

Comment: Welcome @Wesley! Happy that it helped. Next time please document your question with sample data and expected output, this makes it much more easy to understand and respond.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier using CONNECT BY clause -

```
SELECT PRIOR lastname, 
       referred || ' ' || firstname || ' ' || lastname "Referred By:"
FROM customers
CONNECT BY PRIOR customer# = referred
```

Comment: Close, but I need it get the name of the referrer from the same table. This is just giving me say 
Last name Referred By:
GIANA   1003 TAMMY GIANA which is the same name.